# Is “as + adjective” form correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjectives

The guitars in the other store are of a ........quality
but not .......  .

a) higher / as cheap
b) high  /  as cheaply
c) highly  /  as cheaper
d) highest  /   cheap
e) highly  /  the cheapest

The answer key says :  A

Can we use “adjective” after “as” in English?
Does it make sense if we choose A ?

Answer (score 1):

You use the word **as** to indicate that you are comparing a property of two things- either to say that they are the same , or to say that one is less . If you mention two things, you use two **as**:

> My car is **as** fast **as** his [car] - *equal*
>   Ice cream is not **as** nice **as** chocolate - *less*

If you have already referred to the second item, or the listener will understand which one you are talking about, you can omit the second **as** and the second item:

> His car is very fast, but my car is **as** fast - *equal*
>   I love chocolate, but ice cream is not **as** nice - *less*

This is the structure used in this sentence: the second item is the store your are comparing to: maybe the store that you are in as you speak.

> The guitars in the other store are of a  higher quality but not as cheap.

Comment: I got it,thank you very much.

Comment: @ServetSemiz the usual way to show your appreciation on this site is to upvote or accept an answer.